# How to return 'type' field in to_json from activerecord in ruby?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

In a ruby environment, I have an active record model based on a postgres table that has a `type` field.

I need to serialize an instance of this model and I want the text value of `type` to be returned as part of the serialized result, however `.to_json()` does not include this field.

I realize there is some active record magic with single table inheritance going on here, but is it possible to achieve the desired result of outputting the `type` field?
We do use STI here so I can't break that functionality.  I'm guessing there's no way, but maybe there's a workaround?

I did find a workaround, which would be to use the 'methods' syntax in to_json

```
.to_json(:methods=>:type)
```

This does the trick but does feel dirty.
Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: you can try calling `to_json` on parent model

Comment: Using .becomes(parent_class_name).to_json still does not include the 'type' field.  Was that what you meant Eru?

Comment: to_json(:methods => :type) feels a lot less dirty than overriding as_json

Comment: The answer below shows what I meant :) calling `super` and merging the type parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try overriding `as_json` method on your base model:

```
def as_json(*)
  previous = super
  previous[:type] = type
  previous
end
```